# Prove that $\binom nk=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac k2\rfloor}(-1)^j\binom nj\binom{n+k-2j-1}{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Prove combinatorially (using
    inclusion-exclusion) that$ \binom nk=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac
      k2\rfloor}(-1)^j\binom nj\binom{n+k-2j-1}{n-1}$
Hi, everyone. I'm at a loss here. I've been trying to figure out what is being counted here for literally 4 hours. I've learned some things in the meantime, but the minus 2j term confuses me.

I see that we are starting with the j=o set and filtering out some union of other sets. I have been looking for a way to embed subsets from the LHS into subsets count in the first term on the RHS. But no luck. Are we trimming elements from the sides of the n-1 element subsets of the n+k -1 element set that our k element subsets of an n element set are being somehow mapped into? I only ask what is being counted or a hint in that direction. I'm more than willing to complete the details of the proof. I like this stuff, but this one beats ne. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help to write out a few terms of the sum

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}(-1)^j\binom{n}j\binom{n+k-2j-1}{n-1}\;,$$

to get

$$\binom{n}0\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}-\binom{n}1\binom{n+k-3}{n-1}+\binom{n}2\binom{n+k-5}{n-1}-+\ldots\;.$$

The binomial coefficient $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$ is recognizable as the number of ways to distribute $k$ indistinguishable stones amongst $n$ distinguishable boxes. Extending that idea to the other terms, we see that $\binom{n+k-3}{n-1}$ is the number of ways to distribute $k-2$ indistinguishable stones amongst $n$ distinguishable boxes, and in general $\binom{n+k-2j-1}{n-1}$ is the number of ways to distribute $k-2j$ indistinguishable stones amongst $n$ distinguishable boxes.

If this isn’t quite enough of a push, I’ve gone further in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Let’s start with the first term: $\binom{n}0\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}=\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$ is the number of ways to distribute the $k$ stones amongst the $n$ boxes. The ways that have at most one stone in each box correspond exactly to the $k$-element subsets of the $n$ boxes, so to get $\binom{n}k$ we need to subtract the distributions that have more than one stone in some box. If we put two stones into one of the boxes, we have $k-2$ stones left to distribute, and we can still distribute them amongst all $n$ boxes. The distribution can be done in $\binom{n+(k-2)-1}{n-1}=\binom{n+k-3}{n-1}$ ways, and there are $\binom{n}1$ ways to choose the overfilled box, so to a first approximation there are $\binom{n}1\binom{n+k-3}{n-1}$ distributions to be thrown away, leaving us with $\binom{n}0\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}-\binom{n}1\binom{n+k-3}{n-1}$ distributions. Unfortunately, any distribution that has two or more stones in each of *two* boxes has now been subtracted twice, once for each of the boxes, so we have to add those distributions back in. I’ll leave the rest to you.

Comment: You are a god, sir. I've been looking at this the wrong way, obsessed with embeddings, probably because I like them. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Daniel: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

By way of enrichment permit me to present an algebraic proof.

Suppose we seek to verify that
$${n\choose k}
= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} (-1)^j {n\choose j}
{n+k-2j-1\choose n-1}.$$
where $0\le k\le n.$

Introduce
$${n+k-2j-1\choose n-1} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k-2j+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-z)^n} \; dz.$$

Observe carefully  that this integral is  zero when $2j\ge  k+1$ so it
controls the range and we may extend the sum from $\lfloor k/2\rfloor$
to $n.$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-z)^n}
\sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} (-1)^j z^{2j}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-z)^n}
(1-z^2)^n\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} 
(1+z)^n \; dz
\\ = {n\choose k}.$$